# Вызывать функцию от двух событий click?

Tags: jquery, javascript, функции

Делаю так, но почему-то не работает, в чем проблема? пытаюсь передать `habdle` клика функции `SendAjax`, чтобы там заместо `this` обращаться к элементу:

```
function SendAjax(flag, event){
    var type = $(event).val();
    var id_question = $(event).closest('div').attr('rel');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'controller.php',
        data: 'type='+ type + '&id_question=' + id_question + '&flag='+flag,
        success: function(data){

            $('#question_'+id_question).hide();
            id_question++;

            if($("#findID").length) {
                $('#question_'+id_question).show();
            } else {
                SendAjax(1, e)
            }
        }
    });
}

$(function() {
    $("#finish").click(function(e) {
        SendAjax(1, e)
    });

    $(".question input:radio").click(function(e) {
        SendAjax(0, e);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Если вы имеете ввиду двойной клик, то вам нужен [`.dblclick()`](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F_dblclick)

Comment: @Iranda ♦ что не так?

Comment: Посмотрите код, я хочу вызывать одну и ту же функцию по клику

Answer (score 0):

`if($("#findID").length){ 
    $('#question_'+id_question).show();
} 
else {  
    SendAjax(1, e)
}`
    Здесь код уходит в рекурсию. Скорее всего, поэтому все не работает.